# Spring Cloud Consul Cluster connecting with spring boot

Tags: spring, spring-boot, consul, service-discovery, spring-cloud-consul

I'm working with spring cloud consul as a config server and service discovery tool in test environment. according to the consul documentation, consul server need to be at least 3 to 5  recommended servers, and consul will automatically choose a leader server with internal election. The problem is in consul cluster, which server I need to choose to connect in my spring boot service? if leader server changed, what will happen to my service? what is the best practice of using consul server in a real production environment?
I need to mention that, I already studied consul website documentation, but what I need is a real example for architecture and best practice for production environment. note that my services have high TPS  due to USSD transactions in a telecom company. Thanks in advance.

I have tried to connecting to consul server and I'm using it in a test environment as config and service discovery tool. I have nearly 100 service to use consul as their config and discovery server within an internal network with 100 VMs and containers.
I expect a architecture for production environment to use consul in real production environment with pros and cons.